# User meta conventions / name registry, for social media links

Tags: user-meta

The Yoast WordPress-SEO plugin [adds some social media links to user_meta](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/trunk/admin/class-admin.php):

```
function update_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    // Add Google+
    $contactmethods['googleplus'] = __( 'Google+', 'wordpress-seo' );
    // Add Twitter
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = __( 'Twitter username (without @)', 'wordpress-seo' );
    // Add Facebook
    $contactmethods['facebook'] = __( 'Facebook profile URL', 'wordpress-seo' );

    return $contactmethods;
}
```

using bare, namespace-less identifiers for the user_meta keys. I'd like to use these in my about-author box, and add some more (LinkedIn, StackOverflow, GitHub, etc.), and it'd make sense to share the fields and values with any other plugins or widgets that want these too.

Short of better ideas, I was planning to just add keys `'linkedin'`, `'stackoverflow'`, `'github'`, etc.

- Is there a central registry of common user_meta keys, so I can make sure I'm using the same as everyone else? I can't find one from a quick search.
- Yoast specifies 'Twitter username without @', whereas the others are profile URLs. Is that a common convention for user_meta `twitter`, and is that documented anywhere? Arguably Twitter is the only one here where it makes sense to use username not URL, but that'd apply for at least GitHub in my new list too - so I'd like to do the same as everyone else if possible. (I've written my code to cope with URL or username, with or without the '@'.)

Thanks!